# What is the name of this show about microscopic creatures living in a tank?

Tags: story-identification

I saw a show years ago about a guy who found out how to communicate with microscopic creatures living in a tank (air conditioner?) in his house.  I do remember one part where the creature says that it is rumored that one side of their world is warm and the other is cool, at which point the man checks the temperature of the sides of the tank.  The man has a way of enlarging the creature and it turns out to be hostile once it reaches a larger size.  What show is this?

Comment: Live action or cartoon? And how long ago was "years"?

Comment: It was one of those really cheesy TV shows like "Tales from the Darkside" or "Amazing Stories," "Twilight Zone" or something like that.  It was 1980's or thereabouts.

Comment: I would go through wikipedia for these shows - it provides a summary of every episode and eventually you should come across it.(There is also 'the outer limits' which you didn't mention.)

Answer (score 5):

This reminded me of the Simpsons Treehouse of Horror episode where Lisa does exactly the same thing. Knowing that The Simpsons is very good at documenting exactly what it's parodying, I looked up that treehouse of horror episode and, sure enough, it linked me to this:

[The Little People (The Twilight Zone)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Little_People_(The_Twilight_Zone))

You're right, it was The Twilight Zone, specifically Season 3, Episode 28, released March 30th, 1962.

Comment: Hmmm, comparing that episode's plot and the question, I'm starting to think my answer may be wrong, unless the OP is somehow conflating the original episode with The Simpsons episode XD

Comment: Actually just read this synopsis today.  It is a very interesting story!  The microscopic creatures from my show were not human though.  They were like amoeba or something similar.

Comment: I believe it was a scientist with an assistant. They find a way to communicate with microscopic organisms and discover two groups are at war with each other. The scientist is trying to resolve things and enlarges one of the organisms in the process of negotiating peace, maybe? The organism is hostile and is eventually killed.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds familiar - could it be this episode of Monsters (a sci-fi/horror anthology series from 1990?
Micro Minds - Astronomer Dr. Thomas Becker (Troy Donahue) is upset that his graduate student, Paula, hasn't been to class. Paula reveals that she's made contact with an alien species, but the source of the communication seems to be so nearby. This means a ship must be in orbit. Dr. Becker dismisses her claims, but is convinced of the truth after he speaks to "Gok" the alien. He begins to realize he might become world famous. Paula becomes suspicious of Gok's motives, and soon discovers just what Gok really is. But can she stop Dr. Becker in time?

Comment: You got it!  Thanks so much.  I'd been looking for this answer for a while.  I appreciate your research.  You're the man!

Comment: Thanks - glad to help - I know how it is to have this nagging feeling when trying to remember something like this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Simpson's takeoff on the classic short story *[Microcosmic God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcosmic_God)* by Theodore Sturgeon. It was part of [Treehouse of Horror VII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treehouse_of_Horror_VII). They did something pretty similar in Futurama too, [Godfellas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godfellas).